# How can I retrieve the name of the user's current city?

Tags: iphone

I would like to retrieve an iPhoneOS user's current city. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You do an IP to location lookup. This usually involves a database, like [MaxMind's](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity) ones.

Well, I have an iPod Touch, so I forgot that the iPhone might not have an IP mapped to a city at the time (my home ip is static, so that helps too).  You might also read the [Core Location docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/Frameworks/CoreServices/CoreLocation/index.html). As far as I see the `CLLocation` class only communicates in Latitude, Longitude, Altitude, Heading, and Speed. You would need to have your own RTree structure of rough city boundaries to be able to make a determination, or use a web-service call, possibly to [Google Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#Geocoder%20request), or [GeoNames'](http://geonames.org) [`FindNearbyPlaceName`](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html) web service ([St. Gallen Example](http://ws.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceName?lat=47.3&lng=9)).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

[IPhone SDK 3.0](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/08/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit-part-3/) and 
[iPhone Dev SDK](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1634-corelocation-services-convert-long-lat-city.html)

Answer (score 0):

see CLLocationManager class

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
 {





       if (newLocation) {
               longitudeLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude ];
               latitudeLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude ];
                        }




      CLGeocoder * geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

      [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation: locationManager.location completionHandler: 

 ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {




                placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];


               //the below code gives the city name

                NSString *city=placemark.locality; 


                NSLog(@"I am currently at %@",city);


              //String to hold address

              NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
              NSLog(@"I am currently at %@",locatedAt);
              NSMutableArray *FullAddress=[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"];



                  //gives the state 

              NSString * state=[placemark administrativeArea];

              country=[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"Country"];
              CountryCode=[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"CountryCode"];
              Name=[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"Name"];
              State1=[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"State"];
              Street=[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"Street"];


 }];



}
```

see the delegate class for CLPlacemark, it provides a set of information about current location.